# Antonym for "de profundis"?

Tags: idiom, english-to-latin-translation

I'm looking to find out what the Latin for "from the heights" is, as the equivalent of Oscar Wilde's title "*De Profundis*".

Answer (score 4):

How about *de excelsis* (cf. the phrase *gloria in excelsis Deo*)?

From *Oxford Latin Dictionary*:

> **excelsum** ~ī, *n.*
>
> **1** High ground, an eminence, height. **b** a high altitude; (also pl.).
>
> **2** Loftiness (of rank, station, etc.), high position.

Comment: I like this one too. I wonder what the difference between *de coelis* and *de excelsis* would be. Presumably there is a difference in nuance, but I can't tell what it is.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most fitting antonym for *de profundis* is *de caelis* (alternatively spelled *de coelis*).
Literally, this means "from the heavens" or "from the skies".

Take a look at what [*caelum*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1001977) can mean.
I used it in the plural.
The best choice of words depends on your exact context, of course.